# What is this symbol  and how it works?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I have stubled upon a website having this symbol () in their title (see this title, it's there too). It was also picked up by hacker news and is displayed as character. I wonder what is it and how it works?

EDIT: I have attached a screenshot
[image]

Comment: All I am seeing is a square. Meaning, I don't have the font needed to view this character, whatever it is.

Comment: In any case, I don't see how this is a programming question. Are you hoping to use this symbol that's not in my font in your code?

Comment: (fwiw, the bytes seem to be http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f63b/index.htm or 'SMILING CAT FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s the Unicode character [U+1F63B SMILING CAT FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES](http://codepoints.net/U+1F63B). It is a so-called [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji), which, on many mobile devices, gets substituted by colorful graphics. But at the end of a day, it's a simple single character. You could place it in HTML more explicitly like this:

```
<title>&#x1F63B;</title>
```

Comment: (Shameless advertisement: If you have an unknown character, simply place it in the search field over at [codepoints.net](http://codepoints.net), and it shows you the details of that character.)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the “how it works” part of the question, in the HTML context as specified by a tag, the answer is: very poorly. Probably only the following fonts contain it: Quivira, Segoe UI Symbol (new version), Symbola, and DejaVu Sans font (newest versions).

This means that in order to have a fair chance of your visitors actually seeing the character, you would need to use a downloadable font (web font), namely one of the few free fonts that contain it. They are fairly large fonts, so this would be a heavy way as compared with simply using a small image. But if you need to use a large number of such characters in text, then this approach would be feasible.

There’s nothing special in using the character in HTML otherwise, but if you use JavaScript to operate on strings containing it, you need to take into account that this is a Plane 1 character. This means that occupies two code units, i.e. two JavaScript characters.